# Map the Rest Fields when Data Mapping from One Record to Another in Ballerina

Tags: record, datamapper, ballerina

I have a record type `Foo` which is an open record, with a set of defined fields. I have another record `Bar` which is also an open record, with a set of defined fields. I need to map data from `Foo` to `Bar` like this:

```
type Foo record {
    string fs;
    int fi;
};

type Bar record {
    string bs;
    int bi;
};

function transform (Foo foo) returns Bar => {
    bs: foo.fs,
    bi: foo.fi
}
```

How can I map the rest fields from Foo to Bar? I don't need to change the rest field names, but to map them as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Can't think of a direct syntax. You could do something like this though.

```ballerina
public function main() {
    Foo foo = {fs: "hello", fi: 42, "a": 1, "b": true, "c": "cat"};
    Bar bar = {bs: foo.fs, bi: foo.fi};

    foreach string k in foo.keys() {
        if k != "fs" && k != "fi" {
            bar[k] = foo[k];
        }
    }
    io:println(bar);
}
```

`transform()` function would look like this.

```ballerina
function transform(Foo foo) returns Bar {
    Bar bar = {bs: foo.fs, bi: foo.fi};
    foreach string k in foo.keys() {
        if k != "fs" && k != "fi" {
            bar[k] = foo[k];
        }
    }
    return bar;
};
```

Comment: Although this works, if we have a large set of field mappings, the `if` condition becomes complex. I hope for a more data mapper-ish way to handle this.